# Add dates of the same value to display as a single date PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

I would like to write a PL/SQL Code to display dates of the same type to add and display as a single date(MyDate Column) and the amount column should add up

Example Input Table Data:

```
                     MyDate      Amount
                    4/12/2019    1000
                    5/12/2019    2000
                    4/12/2019    3000
```

Output

```
               MyDate        Amount
                4/12/2019     4000
                5/12/2019     2000
```

The condition is aggregate function cannot be used.Please guide me

Comment: Please tag the database you are using.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to use PL/SQL for this. A simple query can be done.

```
SELECT MyDate, SUM(Amount)
FROM your_table
GROUP BY MyDate
ORDER BY MyDate ASC
```

Update:

Since you can't use aggregate functions try:

```
DECLARE
    amount NUMBER := 0;
BEGIN

    FOR date_cursor IN (
        SELECT distinct(MyDate) MyDate
        FROM your_table
        ORDER BY date_c ASC
    ) LOOP

        FOR amount_cursor IN (
            SELECT Amount
            FROM your_table
            WHERE MyDate = date_cursor.MyDate
        ) LOOP

            amount := amount + amount_cursor.amount;

        END LOOP;

        dbms_output.put_line('MyDate: ' || date_cursor.MyDate);
        dbms_output.put_line('Amount: ' || amount);

        amount := 0;

    END LOOP;

END;
```

Comment: My condition is I cannot use aggregates like SUM.

Comment: You want only a query for this or you want the output from PL/SQL code?

Comment: I want the output from PL/SQL Code

Answer (score 1):

Here's a *dynamic SQL* example, just for amusement:

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy';

Session altered.

SQL> select * From test order by mydate;

MYDATE         AMOUNT
---------- ----------
04.12.2019       1000
04.12.2019       3000
05.12.2019       2000
05.12.2019      -5000

SQL> declare
  2    l_sum number;
  3  begin
  4    for cur_r in (select mydate,
  5                    listagg(amount, '+') within group (order by null) l_str
  6                  from test
  7                  group by mydate
  8                 )
  9    loop
 10      execute immediate 'select ' || cur_r.l_str ||' from dual' into l_sum;
 11      dbms_output.put_line(to_char(cur_r.mydate, 'dd.mm.yyyy') ||': '|| l_sum);
 12    end loop;
 13  end;
 14  /
04.12.2019: 4000
05.12.2019: -3000

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Yes, it has its limitations (hint: `listagg`), but - should be OK for homework purposes.